# Why does the relativistic discriminator increase the probability that generated data are real and decrease the probability that real data are real?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, generative-adversarial-networks, discriminator

I was reading [the ESRGAN whitepaper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.00219.pdf), where I came across this line:

> Relativistic discriminator [2] is developed not only to increase the probability that generated data are real but also to simultaneously decrease the probability that real data are real.

Can somebody explain this?